# query on Python list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

I tried:

```
a = [0,1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

this works fine:

```
>>> for q in a:
...     print(q)
... 
0
1
2
3
4
```

But, if I try to change the (mutable) list objects like so, it doesn't work:

```
>>> for q in a:
...     q = 0
... 
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

It seems to me that each time through the loop, q refers to a[n], as n ranges from 0 to 4.  So, it would seem, setting q = 0 ought to make the list all value zero.

Any suggestions that are quite Pythonic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating iterating variable inside loop does not itself update the iterator you iterate through.

```
for q in a:
    q = 0
```

You are just modifying value of `q`, but do not touch the original list `a`.

To make all elements in list to 0, use a list-comprehension:

```
a = [0 for _ in a]
```

Comment: `a = [0 for _ in a]` does not update the list, it replaces it.  It that case you could simply do `a=[0] * len(a)`.

Comment: both good solutions.  I think the second suffers if you want to later change a value, however.  If you do a=[0]*len(a) then I think if you later do a[2]=10, all of a (  a[n] for n in range len(a)  ) will be set to 10, since they all refer to the same object.